# PHP Associative Array To Table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to sort an associative array in ascending in order and then  transfer it to a HTML table and I am currently stumped at an error. I looked for guidelines here on SO and followed instructions on some posts:

[PHP display associative array in HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839537/php-display-associative-array-in-html-table)

But still no luck, here is my attempt:

```
<?php
         function format($g){

          array_multisort($g, SORT_ASC);
          echo "<table>";
          foreach($g as $key=>$row) {
              echo "<tr>";
              foreach($row as $key2=>$row2){
                  echo "<td>" . $row2 . "</td>";
              }
              echo "</tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>";
         }
         $bib = array("Luke"=>"10",
                      "John"=>"30",
                      "Matt"=>"20",
                      "Mark"=>"40");
         format($bib);
       ?>
```

My debugger is telling me there is an error at my for each loop but I don't see how it is wrong unless there is some syntax error that I am not seeing? The error is saying Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Your array is not multi dimensional, so there is no need for the second foreach-loop. What output structure are you expecting? (I.e. what columns and rows should it produce?)

Comment: You're trying to go too deep. The array only has 1 set of key/value pairs. Your second foreach fails because there's nothing to iterate through.

Comment: you have to check whether $row is an array

Comment: Use a recursive function or is_array check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?php

function format($data){
    array_multisort($data, SORT_ASC);
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($data as $key => $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

$bib = array(
    "Luke"=>"10", 
    "John"=>"30",
    "Matt"=>"20",
    "Mark"=>"40"
);

format($bib);

?>
```

Comment: I display one item per loop, One td for key and one td value.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `$bib` is only single array but you use two `foreach` to loop this array

At 2nd loop, your `$row` variable is a string, you can't use `foreach` for this type

Can you try that for single array ?

```
<?php
function format($data) {
    array_multisort($data, SORT_ASC);
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($data as $k => $v) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$k</td>";
        echo "<td>$v</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

$bib = array("Luke"=>"10",
             "John"=>"30",
             "Matt"=>"20",
             "Mark"=>"40");
format($bib);

?>
```

`$k` is `Luke` `John` `Matt` and `Mark`, 
`$v` is `10` `30` `20` and `40`

You can see the foreach example here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Hope this helpful ^^

Comment: this works, but you have a syntax error or 2, thanks for your help

Comment: You are missing a " in your answer, other than that it's useful because it explains the problem. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Why use `_multisort()` on a solitary array???